# Facing issue with for each loop in excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I am using VBA .
I am looping through each row and the column matches value,I am getting the value of  G column with the selected row.

```
  Dim selectedCell As Range
    Dim weekMinutes As Double
    Dim rowNumber As Integer

    usageTracking.Activate
    weeklySheetName = sheetName

     For Each selectedCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
      If selectedCell.Value = customerName Then
'          weekMinutes = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & (selectedCell.row)).Value
           weekMinutes = Cells(selectedCell.row, "G").Value
End If

  Next selectedCell
```

I am able to get value for the first row.
from second row,even though i am having different value,the "weekMinutes" value is showing as 0 instead of the value in the cell.

whats wrong I am doing.

Comment: what values are inside the other rows? Although this seems to work for iterating through rows, I prefer iterating by index (not for each).

Comment: You are not setting any range to `selectedCell`. You have to see the range first

Comment: @Sam `selectedCell` is automatically set by the statement `Next selectedCell`, as it's the control variable of the `Each` loop.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ yes but it is declared at the top as a range. But then never set to anything. Wouldnt that mean it would be 0 all the time?

Comment: @Sam no, that's how `For Each` works: the first time the statement is hit, `selectedCell` becomes the first element in the `ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")`, then it's iterated to the next element thanks to `Next selectedCell`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Ah that makes sense. I generally always make sure that my variables are set and have never come across this. Thanks for clearing it up. Also if that is the case. Wouldn't it loop through every single cell in `A`. Since it is going through the whole range. ALso is `customerName` set elsewhere then AJAY?

Comment: You do well @Sam, that's the safest (and clearest) thing to do. But the built-in just works like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the data of your set, I tell you what I fear the problem being: `customerName`.

```
For Each selectedCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    If selectedCell.Value = customerName Then '<-- customerName is something, I hope...
        weekMinutes = Cells(selectedCell.row, "G").Value
    End If
Next selectedCell '<-- we are to the next cell...
```

...but `customerName` never changed... it is always the same value you enter the loop with.

I guess you're missing a re-assignment of this variable? As for the code you provided, it seems the only criteria that might determine the value of `weekMinutes` to change over the loop.

Moreover, I'd like to let you observe that `weekMinutes` is (potentially) continuosly assigned but never used; when looping through these cells of the range, you will all the time over-write the value and you will only preserve the one got at the last iteration; is it really what you mean to do?

Comment: I have attached a screen shot of my excel,I am having different customerNames in the work sheet.I am assigning the customer name initially one. I am looping thru the cells for that customer name,and if it matches i should get the value in the "G column"

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim customerName As String
 Dim sheetName As Worksheet
 Dim dataFound As Boolean

 Dim selectedCell As Range
 Dim weekMinutes As Double

 Set sheetName = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
 customerName = sheetName.Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
 dataFound = False

 For Each selectedCell In sheetName.Range("A1:A1000")
 If UCase(selectedCell.Value) = UCase(customerName) Then
 weekMinutes = sheetName.Range("G" & selectedCell.Row).Value
```